# Complex Json string to Json map

Tags: java, json, hashmap, gson

I want to parse following json string into HashMap using gson library.

```
{
  'header': {
    'method': 'ADD',
    'request': 'device',
    'version': 'v01',

  },
  'data': {
    'DriverID': 'Modbus-TCP',
    'Devices': [
      {
        'DeviceID': 'X1',
        'DeviceAddress': 'X2',
        'Setting': 'X3',
        'Status': 'X4'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How can I do it? I looked to gson site examples but nothing helps.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will solve your problem :

```
public String parse(String jsonLine) {
    JsonElement jelement = new JsonParser().parse(jsonLine);
    JsonObject  jobject = jelement.getAsJsonObject();
    jobject = jobject.getAsJsonObject("data");
    JsonArray jarray = jobject.getAsJsonArray("Devices");
    jobject = jarray.get(0).getAsJsonObject();
    String result = jobject.get("DeviceID").toString();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Where is the HashMap found in this answer?

Comment: No HashMap found but it did my work. I just wanted to find every values of keys.

Comment: It would be also good if someone can find a logic to HashMap. HashMap is better way to parse.

Comment: @Nilesh.. you can write further logic of HashMap to save all your fetched values into that.. I tried to solve JSON string parsing issue only..  and if you find this solution helpful so please accept it as answer..